# Find the closest shared header with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<h1>First header</h1>

<h2>Second header</h2>
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>

<h2>Third header</h2>
<div>Third div</div>
<div>Fourth div</div>
```

What I need is a general way to find the closest header that is shared by all the divs. In this particular case it would be the `<h1>` header. But the markup could also be:

```
<h1>First header</h1>

<h2>Second header</h2>

<h3>Third header</h3>
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>

<h3>Fourth header</h3>
<div>Third div</div>
<div>Fourth div</div>
```

In this case the first shared header would be the `<h2>` header. More complicated cases are also possible.

I think that the main difficulty is that the closest() and parents() methods don't help because the divs aren't nested under the headers. The prevAll() method seems the most promising, but I haven't found the right approach yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you restructure your HTML to achieve this, if possible. Otherwise the logic would get needlessly complex. Also, you haven't stated which event and from which element you're looking to find the header.

Comment: Are the headers guaranteed to be sequential? (h1, h2, h3...)

Comment: The HTML can't be restructured, as the code will be applied to existing markup in Wikipedia. The starting elements are the divs. The headers are NOT guaranteed to be sequential, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the header you are looking for, is last single common header for the elements you can use smth. like that

```
// Get the collection of the all headers
var $h = $('div').siblings('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');

// Find single headers
var $singles = $h.filter(function(i, el){
    // The hX tag name should be only one in the collection
    return $h.filter(el.tagName).length === 1
});

// Get the last single header
$singles.last().css('color', 'red')
```

But this does not cover cases like `h1(h2(h2;h3))` For such cases you should manually group divs, then group those groups - and so on.

**PS**: The idea, *or the assumption*, behind the code is quite simple: The common (*searched*) header is always single pro level. From your examples, we can write down the logical grouping:
`h1(h2;h2)` and `h1(h2(h3;h3))`. Now the task is to find the most deepest group wich contains all the leefs. From the examples it is clear to see, that such groups containers are always single pro logical tree. 
Now with `siblings()` we get all the headers, filter them by count 1 and take the last one.

But this only works if the logical group contains headers with the same tag name, and none of the nested groups have not the same tag name as of the any of the ancestors. For example such logical grouping wont work `h1(h2(h2;h2)` - here the matched header will be the `h1`.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: I have no idea how your code works, seriously, but it works. If you can explain it further so that I may better understand the limitations and adapt it to the real case, I would be most grateful. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now understand it much better.